# Stopping Thread or Let it Run

Tags: java, multithreading, interrupt

I had a quick question, in Java, is it better to let a thread run continuously after it is done being used, or is it better to try and `.interrupt()` the thread?

My thought is this: Lets say I create threads by a loop so that I can have 100 threads all doing a separate process that does not interrupt the GUI (on the main thread), then the process is finished on all of the threads. Do I stop the threads, or do I just let them continue being open, even though they are not technically doing anything?

My guess is that it would be best to kill the threads so they do not take any resources from the rest of the program. Any ideas?

Comment: What are you doing? Please share your code.

Comment: Generally, if you have a task that you defer to a thread, it should have a clear start, and a clear end. When the execution of your thread passes out of the `run` method, it will end on its own. Just make sure your threads will all cleanly leave the `run` method after whatever they are doing is done, and you'll be gold.

Comment: This is more a discussion question about programming in general. So it does not have a specific example. But here would be a possible pseudo-code: Create a Runnable, put code in side it, create a new thread from the Runnable, thread.start();.

Comment: 100 threads? I hope not! You are much better off using [FutureTask](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/FutureTask.html) instances and an [`Executor`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html).

Comment: But if I use FutureTask, does it process everything on the same thread, just at the time you specify?

Comment: No, that's the general idea. The tasks are spread over a pool of threads. But generally it is little use to have 100 threads sucking up resources if you only have 4/8 CPU cores.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a thread has "finish processing", i.e., exits from the run method, the thread will terminate itself and there's no need to interrupt.

Comment: So is this a feature that is special to Java's "Garbage Collector" or does it apply to other languages like Obj C, C#, etc...

Comment: It actually has little to do with Garbage Collection -- garbage collection deals with freeing memory by detecting unused objects, while the behaviour above has more to do with the JVM threading model. Most languages implements multi-threading in a similar pattern, where you would supply the code to run (the Runnable in Java) and the language library takes care of working with the OS to allocate threads, run the supplied code, and clean up.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This is a very interesting discussion.

Comment: So if this is the threading model of Java, why is there thread.stop() and thread.interrupt() methods?

Comment: Let's consider an example: suppose your thread reads from a socket, and it blocks until a command is received. Your GUI is updated via another thread, and let's say the user cancelled the operation. Your GUI thread now wants to terminate the thread, even though it hasn't finish its processing yet (note: this is the difference b/w this example and yours).  To allow the thread to terminate cleanly and clean up its resources, the main thread should call the interrupt method (stop has been depreciated), and the thread should check and see if it has been interrupted and clean up.

Comment: The TL/DR; version is the interrupt is for cases where you want to stop a running thread, whereas if your thread runs to completion (i.e., exits from its run method), there's no need to call interrupt.

Comment: Interesting. Thank you for taking the time to explain your answer to my question.